# Returning an error code in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm writing some Erlang code and I'm very unsure whether I should let everything fail fast. One problem I find with fail fast is that for the developer/user the exception generated is pretty meaningless. Any idea what I should return which would not give esoteric and hard to read stack traces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you logging with error_logger(3) and have developer look what actually happens behind the scenes. It's recommended to follow [OTP principles](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html) in order to collect all data which is returned by VM when process crashes.

Comment: error_logger looks good. So should I call this from the place throwing the exception or the place catching it? And doesn't it mess up the code?

Comment: You don't need to call anything. Actually there's no need to do that since you install your logger handler when your program starts.

Comment: There are nice articles on http://spawnlink.com/ which also have an example on using such kind of handlers.

Comment: You would also like http://jkvor.com/log-roller. It is a nice logging module which can be used to collect/view logs from different nodes via your browser. Though I haven't touched it yet.

Comment: I searched for "error_logger" on Spawnlink but not a single result

Comment: Indeed, there was info on gen_event, however OTP principles are described well. When you develop your Erlang application which follows OTP principles, you specify all parameters in config files, these include sasl_error_logger, error_logger_mf_dir. The latter allows you to specify directory to save error log files to. Read more at http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html. Actually once you configure your app, you'll probably use the same config options in most of your other applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to fail fast and learn how to read stack traces.

Comment: Does this means that all the support staff who have to monitor the system should learn how to read Erlang error messages?

Comment: Of course everybody whose job it is to diagnose or fix problems need to learn the necessary tools for doing that. Whether that means erlang traces, Python traces, C core dumps, Java traces, or different levels of detail knowledge. You probably want a few specialists for specific technologies, and many generalists who know the basics and can redirect to the appropriate specialists.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't realise that it is part of the support people's job. I'll let them know. I know they won't be happy though, but it is better for me, as currently they always come to me when there is a production error (about 20 times a day).

Comment: The ejabberd FAQ has a list of common error messages: http://www.ejabberd.im/common-errors

I found that quite useful even before I learnt Erlang; I could usually spot key words from the error message I got in that list.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle in Erlang is:

> Make it crash!

I found quite useful to avoid the so called *defensive programming*. The concept is explained in a bit more detail in the Erlang Programming Rules page:

http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR11

Moreover, even if some of the Erlang errors can be a bit cryptic, a nice way to deal with is **trace** them! Tracing in Erlang is pretty simple. Have a look to this quick reference:

http://aloiroberto.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/tracing-erlang-functions/

or simply refer to the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since Erlang is a functional language errors are often easily spot if you tend to write [Pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), because pure function given one arguments will always return the same result. Thus, having the stack trace, once you found the failed function you can figure out what caused an error. Opposed to imperative programming you don't need to spend a lot of time debugging your code, often you don't even need the debugger, and searching the error turns to an interesting game. [This](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/fp.html) article is useful.